# Keeping content in two table columns stuck to the roof of the respective table column 

Tags: css

When using tables in a CSS-based layout, I've noticed if I have a table with 4 columns (2 on the side are small for spacing, 2 in the middle are for content), when I type content in one of the two middle columns, it will stay at the top, which is perfect.

However, if I type content in the other middle column, and press enter, the content in the other middle content will come down.

This means I can never type content in the two columns while keeping the content in both columns glued to the top (roof) of the table column. I have tried everything, is there a way I can do this? If I can't do this, my content looks wonky as it's not level in the two columns, and thus unprofessional.

Comment: Might help if you posted some code. Is it actually a table, or are you using divs to make the columns?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution would be to create a rule which aligns text to the top of table cells.

```
td {
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

As an alternative, you can use column groups and columns to specify the vertical alignment of different columns. An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Table Columns Alignments</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col valign="bottom"/>
            <col />
            <col valign="top"/>
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>aligned to bottom</td>
                <td>no special<br/>alignment<br/><p>here</p></td>
                <td>aligned to top</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the browser support for this is not across the board, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem entirely but you could look at the [vertical-align css property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a table for layout anyway, which is kinda evil, but sometimes neccessary, and often faster and cheaper, how about just setting valign="top" in the table cell markup?

It's not a css solution, but is a tried and proven method from the bad old days of table layouts.